# How should I encode my href attribute in my WebMatrix C# site?

Tags: c#, url, href, webmatrix, encode

First off, I have been doing a lot of reading/researching on this topic, but I am still a bit confused as to what the best practice for this is.

I have checked AND READ ALL of the following very helpful and informative pages on the subject:

> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437314.aspx
>
> [how to encode href attribute in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189489/how-to-encode-href-attribute-in-html)
>
> [HttpServerUtility.UrlPathEncode vs HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode)

**This is my setup (the content variable will later be rendered with `Html.Raw()`):**

```
content += "<a class=\"contentLink\" href=\"" + subRow.linkHref + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + subRow.linkText + "</a>";
```

The encoding of `subRow.linkText` is simple enough (just a simple HtmlEncode method will secure that), however I am confused, as others have been, on how to encode the href attribute given the resources (shown in above links) and best practices of today.

**UPDATE: All of what is inserted into the 'href' attribute is user-input. I want it this way so that they can either path to something they post on Google Drive or any other related site or even a relational path (programmatically constructed) to an internal .pdf file or picture, should they choose.**

I do get the differences between the methods I have available to me, but I am not sure which or how many I should apply and in what order? Should I even use `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode`?

The context of this question is from the perspective of wanting my site not to break and, of course, preventing XSS.

**UPDATE:**

I attempted to test inserting javascript into various portions of a url using the user-input that will later be used in the `href` attribute, and I have noticed a couple of oddities.

I am currently testing with this encoding setup:

```
content += "<a class=\"contentLink\" href=\"" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(subRow.linkHref)) + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(subRow.linkText) + "</a>";
```

In effect, first I am url encoding (with UrlPathEncode), then I am HTML encoding. I believe this may be the correct method as the HTML encoded text will hit the DOM and should still render fine as a URL (*I think*).

However, as I stated, I have noticed a couple of oddities.

1. I used this as the user input: `http://localhost:10226/home.cshtml?javascript:var a = "hi"; alert(a); void(0);` and no javascript executes, but I am not convinced it is necessarily because of my encoding (that is, I could see advanced browsers no longer allowing javascript to be ran from the url, as it is a huge security hole and bad practice, in general, from my understanding, but, of course, I can't bank on this).
2. After clicking the link that shows up using this test user-input the address bar reads: `http://localhost:10226/home.cshtml?javascript:var%20a%20=%20%22hi%22;%20alert(a);%20void(0);` And this is where I get a little confused. From the research shown in the links above, `UrlPathEncode` is supposed to ignore encoding after the `?`, however you can clearly see that it `%` encoded the spaces in the query string portion of this url. This is a good thing, I suppose, but not consistent with what I understand of the documentation.

I suppose I am still at a loss, but every local and external links I have tried have neither been broken nor dangerous that I can tell, so I will continue to use this until my understanding of this is otherwise clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to what you are trying to do as reading over your post has given me some "Analysis Paralisys" but I may be able to offer a different perspective. I have come to rely on the practice of calling a java script function and that should give you more options in building a url string. This is the HTML:

```
         <a class="link_looks_like_button" onclick=openWin("../SendMail/ContractorInfo",700,850);>Add/Update Contractor</a>
```

Then down in my Javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function openWin(url, width, height)
    {
        myWindow=window.open(url,'_blank','width='+width+',height='+height);
        myWindow.focus();
    }
```

Of course now that you have it down in the java script you can examine your "url" string with firebug and manipulate it using java script.

I hope this helps.

Here is a link to the JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fonsecat/gzzzU/25/

Comment: I will try to get this into a jsfiddle example

Comment: I appreciate your input and if I didn't already use other development tools to tell what my url "actually" looks like in real text, this would be very helpful. However, I like to keep ALL javascript (or scripts of ANY kind) out of the DOM. I never use "onclick", "onmouseover", etc. I set up event handlers in an external javascript file. Not 100% sure if that is good practice always, but I heard somewhere that it was better not to insert javascript into the DOM. Anyway, I would (as probably others would, as well) still love to see a jsfiddle of your code, if you were so inclined :)

Comment: You got it! I have updated the answer with a link to JSFiddle

Comment: I think I see what you're doing, but I don't think it works. Nothing happens when I click the "Sample" button. I'd give advice, but I very rarely (if ever) have used `Window.Open`