# How to encode url passwords in href?

Tags: php, html

How do I need to encode special chars in a urls password:

```
<a href="ftp://user:password@server.com/html">ftp</a>
```

I have problem if the first character of the password is #

Chrome does change `<a href="ftp://user:#password...` to `ftp://user/password` if you click on the link.

Comment: It’s a URL, so use URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it working if `urlencode(password)` and `htmlspecialchars()` over the whole link as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189489/how-to-encode-href-attribute-in-html?rq=1).

Problem is that FileZilla does not decode the password correctly.

Comment: Filezilla is a FTP-CLIENT not a Browser! Register your Server in Filezilla and foreget appear login-informations in your link

Comment: @donald123 Yes, it is a FTP client and if you copy a FTP link into Filezilla you get host, username and password with one step.

Comment: @Gumbo thank you but `rawurlencode('#')` is still `%23` I think this needs to be fixed in Filezilla.